# How can I open a YouTube link with youtube app in Android (using Dreamweaver CS6)?

Tags: android, jquery, html, mobile, dreamweaver

I'm using adobe dreamweaver CS6 and jQuery Mobile to develop Android applications. After developing, my apps are put together by phonegap. Here I have the following problem: I have some buttons related to YouTube links, but I want them to open in the YouTube app. I'd like to work only in Dreamweaver, and use plug-ins only if necessary. I've already read about "intents" and "URL-s", but I don't know how to use them and how they work in dreamweaver. I haven't found any good tutorials on it yet.

Please be detailed if you can.

Comment: "I'm using adobe dreamweaver CS6 and jQuery Mobile to develop Android applications." - You are not developing Android apps. You are developing web apps that happen to work on Android. Users will know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can simply link to youtube. The youtube app will handle the request and will start if the user allows that.

The youtube app has a special intent handler where the urls to youtube will be catched. So normally on the first link to youtube the user will be asked if the youtube app should be started or the browser(s).

Such a link what works in a native android application would be: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx

So in dreamweaver/html it should look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx">Some Video</a>
```