# Creating deeplink for youtube app

Tags: android, facebook, youtube, deep-linking

How do I create deep-link for YouTube app, when clicked on particular YouTube video in mysite that should open YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by default. Whenever I open a link to youtube in any website, it opens up my youtube app, or asks me what app do I want to use to open it (if no app is set to default).  Make sure you don't have any web browser set as default to open youtube videos on your mobile device.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663113/how-can-i-open-a-youtube-link-with-youtube-app-in-android-using-dreamweaver-cs6) for more detail.